# When gaming computer freezes with a blank screen and a buzzing sound

Tags: crash, black-screen-of-death

I have a problem with random freezes when playing games. Sometimes it's fine for hours, other times it dosn't last even one. I tried googling around and I found recomendations to update my graphics drivers and to test for overheating. The graphics drivers haven't helped worked and Furmark created a consistant heat higher than I get during a crash.

I even tried running a game using the Linux dual boot and WINE, that crashed too.

Here are the tempreture logs leading up to the latest crash. The GPU dosn't hit 80, and I've hit 90 with no crash on firmark.

```
  DATE      TIME      MHz    CPU_0 CPU_1 CPU_2 CPU_3  LOAD%  GPU
04/05/12  15:21:00  3200.16    63    58    57    56    15.4   77
04/05/12  15:21:05  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.8   76
04/05/12  15:21:10  3200.16    62    59    58    55    15.1   78
04/05/12  15:21:15  3200.16    63    59    58    56    16.5   77
04/05/12  15:21:20  3200.16    64    58    58    57    15.3   77
04/05/12  15:21:25  3200.16    63    58    59    56    15.8   78
04/05/12  15:21:30  3200.16    63    58    58    57    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:21:35  3200.16    63    58    58    56    17.0   77
04/05/12  15:21:40  3200.16    63    59    59    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:21:45  3200.16    63    58    58    58    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:21:50  3200.16    63    58    58    58    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:21:55  3200.16    63    58    59    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:00  3200.16    63    58    58    57    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:21:05  3200.16    63    58    58    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:21:10  3200.16    63    57    58    56    15.3   78
04/05/12  15:21:15  3200.16    64    58    58    56    15.4   78
04/05/12  15:21:20  3200.16    63    58    58    56    15.4   77
04/05/12  15:21:25  3200.16    62    58    58    57    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:21:30  3200.16    62    58    58    57    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:21:35  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:21:40  3200.16    63    58    58    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:21:45  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:21:50  3200.16    62    59    58    58    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:21:55  3200.16    63    58    58    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:00  3200.16    63    58    58    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:05  3200.16    63    58    58    56    16.3   77
04/05/12  15:22:10  3200.16    64    58    59    56    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:22:15  3200.16    63    58    60    57    17.2   77
04/05/12  15:22:20  3200.16    63    58    58    56    15.5   78
04/05/12  15:22:25  3200.16    63    58    60    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:30  3200.16    63    59    59    57    15.6   76
04/05/12  15:22:35  3200.16    64    59    60    57    17.7   77
04/05/12  15:22:40  3200.16    63    59    58    57    16.0   77
04/05/12  15:22:45  3200.16    64    58    58    57    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:22:50  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:22:55  3200.16    63    58    59    57    15.8   78
04/05/12  15:23:00  3200.16    63    59    58    57    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:22:05  3200.16    62    58    57    58    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:10  3200.16    63    58    59    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:15  3200.16    63    59    58    56    17.1   77
04/05/12  15:22:20  3200.16    63    58    59    57    16.0   77
04/05/12  15:22:25  3200.16    63    58    58    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:22:30  3200.16    63    59    59    57    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:22:35  3200.16    64    59    58    58    21.0   77
04/05/12  15:22:40  3200.16    63    59    58    58    16.0   77
04/05/12  15:22:45  3200.16    64    59    59    57    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:22:50  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.8   78
04/05/12  15:22:55  3200.16    63    59    58    57    15.8   78
04/05/12  15:23:00  3200.16    63    59    57    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:23:05  3200.16    64    58    58    58    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:23:10  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:23:15  3200.16    64    59    58    57    16.6   77
04/05/12  15:23:20  3200.16    63    59    58    58    16.0   77
04/05/12  15:23:25  3200.16    63    58    58    57    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:23:30  3200.16    63    59    58    56    15.4   78
04/05/12  15:23:35  3200.16    64    60    59    61    17.7   77
04/05/12  15:23:40  3200.16    63    59    58    57    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:23:45  1600.08    53    54    53    52     4.4   76
04/05/12  15:23:50  3200.16    63    59    57    56    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:23:55  3200.16    63    58    57    57    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:24:00  3200.16    63    58    58    58    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:23:05  3200.16    64    59    58    56    15.6   77
04/05/12  15:23:10  3200.16    64    59    58    57    15.9   77
04/05/12  15:23:15  3200.16    63    59    58    59    16.7   77
04/05/12  15:23:20  3200.16    64    58    58    58    16.0   77
04/05/12  15:23:25  3200.16    64    58    58    57    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:23:30  3200.16    64    58    58    57    15.2   78
04/05/12  15:23:35  3200.16    63    59    59    58    17.8   77
04/05/12  15:23:40  3200.16    63    59    59    58    15.8   77
04/05/12  15:23:45  1600.08    53    54    53    52     4.7   76
04/05/12  15:23:50  3200.16    63    59    57    56    16.9   77
04/05/12  15:23:55  3200.16    63    58    59    56    15.7   77
04/05/12  15:24:00  3200.16    63    58    59    57    15.9   77
```

I also got a dmp file, here's what BlueScreenView gave me. The first three lines were in red, the summery says that the crash was casued by hal.dll and the address hal.dll+12903

```
Filename    Address in Stack    From Address    To Address  Size    Time Stamp  Time String Product Name    File Description    File Version    Company Full Path
hal.dll hal.dll+12903   fffff800`033e0000   fffff800`03429000   0x00049000  0x4a5bdf08  14/07/2009 02:27:36                     
ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+185923 fffff800`02e05000   fffff800`033e0000   0x005db000  0x4ec7a284  19/11/2011 13:35:16 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NT Kernel & System  6.1.7600.16917 (win7_gdr.111118-2330)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe    
pci.sys pci.sys+9aff    fffff880`0108f000   fffff880`010c2000   0x00033000  0x4a5bc117  14/07/2009 00:19:51                     
kdcom.dll       fffff800`00bc4000   fffff800`00bce000   0x0000a000  0x4d4d40d9  05/02/2011 13:21:45                     
mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll       fffff880`00c26000   fffff880`00c6a000   0x00044000  0x4a5bdf66  14/07/2009 02:29:10                     
PSHED.dll       fffff880`00c6a000   fffff880`00c7e000   0x00014000  0x4a5be027  14/07/2009 02:32:23 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Platform Specific Hardware Error Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\PSHED.dll   
CLFS.SYS        fffff880`00c7e000   fffff880`00cdc000   0x0005e000  0x4a5bc11d  14/07/2009 00:19:57                     
CI.dll      fffff880`00cdc000   fffff880`00d9c000   0x000c0000  0x4a5be01d  14/07/2009 02:32:13                     
Wdf01000.sys        fffff880`00e0e000   fffff880`00eb2000   0x000a4000  0x4a5bc19f  14/07/2009 00:22:07                     
WDFLDR.SYS      fffff880`00eb2000   fffff880`00ec1000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bc11a  14/07/2009 00:19:54                     
sptd.sys        fffff880`00ec1000   fffff880`00fe7000   0x00126000  0x4ad24632  11/10/2009 21:55:14                     
WMILIB.SYS      fffff880`00fe7000   fffff880`00ff0000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc117  14/07/2009 00:19:51                     
SCSIPORT.SYS        fffff880`00d9c000   fffff880`00dcb000   0x0002f000  0x4a5bcac0  14/07/2009 01:01:04                     
ACPI.sys        fffff880`01021000   fffff880`01078000   0x00057000  0x4a5bc106  14/07/2009 00:19:34                     
msisadrv.sys        fffff880`01078000   fffff880`01082000   0x0000a000  0x4a5bc0fe  14/07/2009 00:19:26                     
vdrvroot.sys        fffff880`01082000   fffff880`0108f000   0x0000d000  0x4a5bcadb  14/07/2009 01:01:31                     
partmgr.sys     fffff880`010c2000   fffff880`010d7000   0x00015000  0x4a5bc11e  14/07/2009 00:19:58                     
volmgr.sys      fffff880`010d7000   fffff880`010ec000   0x00015000  0x4a5bc11d  14/07/2009 00:19:57                     
volmgrx.sys     fffff880`010ec000   fffff880`01148000   0x0005c000  0x4a5bc141  14/07/2009 00:20:33                     
pciide.sys      fffff880`01148000   fffff880`0114f000   0x00007000  0x4a5bc115  14/07/2009 00:19:49                     
PCIIDEX.SYS     fffff880`0114f000   fffff880`0115f000   0x00010000  0x4a5bc114  14/07/2009 00:19:48                     
mountmgr.sys        fffff880`0115f000   fffff880`01179000   0x0001a000  0x4a5bc11a  14/07/2009 00:19:54                     
atapi.sys       fffff880`01179000   fffff880`01182000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc113  14/07/2009 00:19:47                     
ataport.SYS     fffff880`01182000   fffff880`011ac000   0x0002a000  0x4a5bc118  14/07/2009 00:19:52                     
msahci.sys      fffff880`011ac000   fffff880`011b7000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bcabd  14/07/2009 01:01:01                     
amdxata.sys     fffff880`011b7000   fffff880`011c2000   0x0000b000  0x4ba3a3ca  19/03/2010 17:18:18                     
fltmgr.sys      fffff880`01211000   fffff880`0125d000   0x0004c000  0x4a5bc11f  14/07/2009 00:19:59                     
fileinfo.sys        fffff880`0125d000   fffff880`01271000   0x00014000  0x4a5bc481  14/07/2009 00:34:25                     
Ntfs.sys        fffff880`0145c000   fffff880`015fe000   0x001a2000  0x4d79996d  11/03/2011 04:39:25                     
msrpc.sys       fffff880`01271000   fffff880`012cf000   0x0005e000  0x4a5bc17c  14/07/2009 00:21:32                     
ksecdd.sys      fffff880`01400000   fffff880`0141a000   0x0001a000  0x4ec48579  17/11/2011 04:54:33                     
cng.sys     fffff880`012cf000   fffff880`01342000   0x00073000  0x4ec48cfb  17/11/2011 05:26:35                     
pcw.sys     fffff880`0141a000   fffff880`0142b000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc0ff  14/07/2009 00:19:27                     
Fs_Rec.sys      fffff880`0142b000   fffff880`01435000   0x0000a000  0x4a5bc111  14/07/2009 00:19:45                     
ndis.sys        fffff880`01653000   fffff880`01745000   0x000f2000  0x4a5bc184  14/07/2009 00:21:40                     
NETIO.SYS       fffff880`01745000   fffff880`017a5000   0x00060000  0x4bbe946f  09/04/2010 03:43:59                     
ksecpkg.sys     fffff880`017a5000   fffff880`017d0000   0x0002b000  0x4ec48d32  17/11/2011 05:27:30                     
tcpip.sys       fffff880`01802000   fffff880`01a00000   0x001fe000  0x4e83eb7f  29/09/2011 04:52:31                     
fwpkclnt.sys        fffff880`01600000   fffff880`0164a000   0x0004a000  0x4a5bc164  14/07/2009 00:21:08                     
vmstorfl.sys        fffff880`017d0000   fffff880`017e0000   0x00010000  0x4a5bc67e  14/07/2009 00:42:54                     
volsnap.sys     fffff880`01342000   fffff880`0138e000   0x0004c000  0x4a5bc128  14/07/2009 00:20:08                     
spldr.sys       fffff880`017e0000   fffff880`017e8000   0x00008000  0x4a0858bb  11/05/2009 17:56:27                     
rdyboost.sys        fffff880`0138e000   fffff880`013c8000   0x0003a000  0x4a5bc48a  14/07/2009 00:34:34                     
mup.sys     fffff880`017e8000   fffff880`017fa000   0x00012000  0x4a5bc201  14/07/2009 00:23:45                     
hwpolicy.sys        fffff880`0164a000   fffff880`01653000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc0fa  14/07/2009 00:19:22                     
fvevol.sys      fffff880`011c2000   fffff880`011fc000   0x0003a000  0x4abd7db2  26/09/2009 03:34:26                     
disk.sys        fffff880`01435000   fffff880`0144b000   0x00016000  0x4a5bc11d  14/07/2009 00:19:57                     
CLASSPNP.SYS        fffff880`013c8000   fffff880`013f8000   0x00030000  0x4a5bc11e  14/07/2009 00:19:58                     
cdrom.sys       fffff880`00dcb000   fffff880`00df5000   0x0002a000  0x4a5bc11a  14/07/2009 00:19:54                     
MpFilter.sys        fffff880`02c1a000   fffff880`02c4b000   0x00031000  0x4d9cc801  06/04/2011 21:07:29                     
Null.SYS        fffff880`02c4b000   fffff880`02c54000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc109  14/07/2009 00:19:37                     
Beep.SYS        fffff880`02c54000   fffff880`02c5b000   0x00007000  0x4a5bca8d  14/07/2009 01:00:13                     
vga.sys     fffff880`02c5b000   fffff880`02c69000   0x0000e000  0x4a5bc587  14/07/2009 00:38:47                     
VIDEOPRT.SYS        fffff880`02c69000   fffff880`02c8e000   0x00025000  0x4a5bc58b  14/07/2009 00:38:51                     
watchdog.sys        fffff880`02c8e000   fffff880`02c9e000   0x00010000  0x4a5bc53f  14/07/2009 00:37:35                     
RDPCDD.sys      fffff880`02c9e000   fffff880`02ca7000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce62  14/07/2009 01:16:34                     
rdpencdd.sys        fffff880`02ca7000   fffff880`02cb0000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce62  14/07/2009 01:16:34                     
rdprefmp.sys        fffff880`02cb0000   fffff880`02cb9000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce63  14/07/2009 01:16:35                     
Msfs.SYS        fffff880`02cb9000   fffff880`02cc4000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bc113  14/07/2009 00:19:47                     
Npfs.SYS        fffff880`02cc4000   fffff880`02cd5000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc114  14/07/2009 00:19:48                     
tdx.sys     fffff880`02cd5000   fffff880`02cf3000   0x0001e000  0x4a5bc16b  14/07/2009 00:21:15                     
TDI.SYS     fffff880`02cf3000   fffff880`02d00000   0x0000d000  0x4a5bc16e  14/07/2009 00:21:18                     
afd.sys     fffff880`02d00000   fffff880`02d89000   0x00089000  0x4efa940c  28/12/2011 04:59:08                     
netbt.sys       fffff880`02d89000   fffff880`02dce000   0x00045000  0x4a5bc178  14/07/2009 00:21:28                     
ws2ifsl.sys     fffff880`02dce000   fffff880`02dd9000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bccf9  14/07/2009 01:10:33                     
wfplwf.sys      fffff880`02dd9000   fffff880`02de2000   0x00009000  0x4a5bccb6  14/07/2009 01:09:26                     
pacer.sys       fffff880`00c00000   fffff880`00c26000   0x00026000  0x4a5bccc5  14/07/2009 01:09:41                     
vpcnfltr.sys        fffff880`02de2000   fffff880`02df6000   0x00014000  0x4ab97aae  23/09/2009 02:32:30                     
netbios.sys     fffff880`02c00000   fffff880`02c0f000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bccb6  14/07/2009 01:09:26                     
serial.sys      fffff880`04075000   fffff880`04092000   0x0001d000  0x4a5bcaa8  14/07/2009 01:00:40                     
wanarp.sys      fffff880`04092000   fffff880`040ad000   0x0001b000  0x4a5bcced  14/07/2009 01:10:21                     
vpcvmm.sys      fffff880`040ad000   fffff880`04103180   0x00056180  0x4ab97ab6  23/09/2009 02:32:38                     
termdd.sys      fffff880`04104000   fffff880`04118000   0x00014000  0x4a5bce64  14/07/2009 01:16:36                     
rdbss.sys       fffff880`04118000   fffff880`04169000   0x00051000  0x4a5bc219  14/07/2009 00:24:09                     
nsiproxy.sys        fffff880`04169000   fffff880`04175000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bc15e  14/07/2009 00:21:02                     
mssmbios.sys        fffff880`04175000   fffff880`04180000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bc3be  14/07/2009 00:31:10                     
discache.sys        fffff880`04180000   fffff880`0418f000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bc52e  14/07/2009 00:37:18                     
csc.sys     fffff880`04280000   fffff880`04303000   0x00083000  0x4a5bc22a  14/07/2009 00:24:26                     
dfsc.sys        fffff880`04303000   fffff880`04321000   0x0001e000  0x4db78623  27/04/2011 03:57:39                     
blbdrive.sys        fffff880`04321000   fffff880`04332000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc4df  14/07/2009 00:35:59                     
tunnel.sys      fffff880`04332000   fffff880`04358000   0x00026000  0x4a5bccc1  14/07/2009 01:09:37                     
intelppm.sys        fffff880`04358000   fffff880`0436e000   0x00016000  0x4a5bc0fd  14/07/2009 00:19:25                     
nvlddmkm.sys        fffff880`0fe34000   fffff880`10b52000   0x00d1e000  0x4f4e68c4  29/02/2012 19:04:52                     
nvBridge.kmd        fffff880`10b52000   fffff880`10b53180   0x00001180  0x4d27c482  08/01/2011 02:57:22                     
dxgkrnl.sys     fffff880`04450000   fffff880`04544000   0x000f4000  0x4d3fa1a0  26/01/2011 05:22:56                     
dxgmms1.sys     fffff880`04544000   fffff880`0458a000   0x00046000  0x4d3fa174  26/01/2011 05:22:12                     
usbuhci.sys     fffff880`0458a000   fffff880`04597000   0x0000d000  0x4d8c0a8f  25/03/2011 04:22:55                     
USBPORT.SYS     fffff880`04597000   fffff880`045ed000   0x00056000  0x4d8c0a97  25/03/2011 04:23:03                     
usbehci.sys     fffff880`045ed000   fffff880`045fe000   0x00011000  0x4d8c0a91  25/03/2011 04:22:57                     
HDAudBus.sys        fffff880`04400000   fffff880`04424000   0x00024000  0x4a5bcbf5  14/07/2009 01:06:13                     
1394ohci.sys        fffff880`10b54000   fffff880`10b92000   0x0003e000  0x4a5bcc30  14/07/2009 01:07:12                     
Rt64win7.sys        fffff880`10b92000   fffff880`10bc4000   0x00032000  0x49a65b0d  26/02/2009 10:04:13                     
i8042prt.sys        fffff880`04424000   fffff880`04442000   0x0001e000  0x4a5bc11d  14/07/2009 00:19:57                     
kbdclass.sys        fffff880`10bc4000   fffff880`10bd3000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bc116  14/07/2009 00:19:50                     
VMkbd.sys       fffff880`04442000   fffff880`0444d000   0x0000b000  0x4b5a836f  23/01/2010 06:04:47                     
serenum.sys     fffff880`10bd3000   fffff880`10bdf000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bcaa1  14/07/2009 01:00:33                     
av1shsvl.SYS        fffff880`0436e000   fffff880`043b3000   0x00045000  0x4a5cf4d7  14/07/2009 22:12:55                     
wmiacpi.sys     fffff880`10bdf000   fffff880`10be8000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc3b6  14/07/2009 00:31:02                     
CompositeBus.sys        fffff880`10be8000   fffff880`10bf8000   0x00010000  0x4a5bcaa1  14/07/2009 01:00:33                     
AgileVpn.sys        fffff880`0fe00000   fffff880`0fe16000   0x00016000  0x4a5bccf0  14/07/2009 01:10:24                     
rasl2tp.sys     fffff880`043b3000   fffff880`043d7000   0x00024000  0x4a5bcce3  14/07/2009 01:10:11                     
ndistapi.sys        fffff880`0fe16000   fffff880`0fe22000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bccd8  14/07/2009 01:10:00                     
ndiswan.sys     fffff880`04200000   fffff880`0422f000   0x0002f000  0x4a5bcce3  14/07/2009 01:10:11                     
raspppoe.sys        fffff880`0422f000   fffff880`0424a000   0x0001b000  0x4a5bcce9  14/07/2009 01:10:17                     
raspptp.sys     fffff880`0424a000   fffff880`0426b000   0x00021000  0x4a5bccea  14/07/2009 01:10:18                     
rassstp.sys     fffff880`043d7000   fffff880`043f1000   0x0001a000  0x4a5bccf1  14/07/2009 01:10:25                     
tapoas.sys      fffff880`0fe22000   fffff880`0fe2f000   0x0000d000  0x4c3a627f  12/07/2010 01:31:59                     
tap0901.sys     fffff880`043f1000   fffff880`043fe000   0x0000d000  0x4b22da33  12/12/2009 00:48:03                     
rdpbus.sys      fffff880`0426b000   fffff880`04276000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bceaa  14/07/2009 01:17:46                     
mouclass.sys        fffff880`0418f000   fffff880`0419e000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bc116  14/07/2009 00:19:50                     
swenum.sys      fffff880`0444d000   fffff880`0444e480   0x00001480  0x4a5bca92  14/07/2009 01:00:18                     
ks.sys      fffff880`0419e000   fffff880`041e1000   0x00043000  0x4b8f37d9  04/03/2010 05:32:25                     
umbus.sys       fffff880`041e1000   fffff880`041f3000   0x00012000  0x4a5bcc20  14/07/2009 01:06:56                     
vpcusb.sys      fffff880`04000000   fffff880`0401d000   0x0001d000  0x4ab97ab7  23/09/2009 02:32:39                     
usbrpm.sys      fffff880`0401d000   fffff880`0402c000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bd2c2  14/07/2009 01:35:14                     
USBD.SYS        fffff880`045fe000   fffff880`045fff00   0x00001f00  0x4d8c0a8b  25/03/2011 04:22:51                     
vmnetadapter.sys        fffff880`10bf8000   fffff880`10c00000   0x00008000  0x4a800ce5  10/08/2009 13:04:53                     
VMNET.SYS       fffff880`04276000   fffff880`04280000   0x0000a000  0x4a800ce2  10/08/2009 13:04:50                     
vpchbus.sys     fffff880`0402c000   fffff880`04068000   0x0003c000  0x4ab97ab0  23/09/2009 02:32:32                     
usbhub.sys      fffff880`04c26000   fffff880`04c80000   0x0005a000  0x4d8c0aaa  25/03/2011 04:23:22                     
NDProxy.SYS     fffff880`04c80000   fffff880`04c95000   0x00015000  0x4a5bccdd  14/07/2009 01:10:05                     
HdAudio.sys     fffff880`04c95000   fffff880`04cf1000   0x0005c000  0x4a5bcc23  14/07/2009 01:06:59                     
portcls.sys     fffff880`04cf1000   fffff880`04d2e000   0x0003d000  0x4a5bcc03  14/07/2009 01:06:27                     
drmk.sys        fffff880`04d2e000   fffff880`04d50000   0x00022000  0x4a5bd8e5  14/07/2009 02:01:25                     
ksthunk.sys     fffff880`04d50000   fffff880`04d55200   0x00005200  0x4a5bca93  14/07/2009 01:00:19                     
win32k.sys      fffff960`000c0000   fffff960`003d4000   0x00314000  0x00000000                          
Dxapi.sys       fffff880`04d56000   fffff880`04d62000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bc574  14/07/2009 00:38:28                     
udfs.sys        fffff880`04d62000   fffff880`04db6000   0x00054000  0x4a5bc1f9  14/07/2009 00:23:37                     
monitor.sys     fffff880`04db6000   fffff880`04dc4000   0x0000e000  0x4a5bc58c  14/07/2009 00:38:52                     
TSDDD.dll       fffff960`004c0000   fffff960`004ca000   0x0000a000  0x00000000                          
hidusb.sys      fffff880`04dc4000   fffff880`04dd2000   0x0000e000  0x4a5bcbfe  14/07/2009 01:06:22                     
HIDCLASS.SYS        fffff880`04dd2000   fffff880`04deb000   0x00019000  0x4a5bcbfd  14/07/2009 01:06:21                     
HIDPARSE.SYS        fffff880`04deb000   fffff880`04df3080   0x00008080  0x4a5bcbf9  14/07/2009 01:06:17                     
cdd.dll     fffff960`00660000   fffff960`00687000   0x00027000  0x00000000                          
mouhid.sys      fffff880`04c00000   fffff880`04c0d000   0x0000d000  0x4a5bca94  14/07/2009 01:00:20                     
luafv.sys       fffff880`05a78000   fffff880`05a9b000   0x00023000  0x4a5bc295  14/07/2009 00:26:13                     
WudfPf.sys      fffff880`05a9b000   fffff880`05abc000   0x00021000  0x4a5bcbd1  14/07/2009 01:05:37                     
crashdmp.sys        fffff880`05abc000   fffff880`05aca000   0x0000e000  0x4a5bcabd  14/07/2009 01:01:01                     
dump_dumpata.sys        fffff880`05aca000   fffff880`05ad6000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bc113  14/07/2009 00:19:47                     
dump_msahci.sys     fffff880`05ad6000   fffff880`05ae1000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bcabd  14/07/2009 01:01:01                     
dump_dumpfve.sys        fffff880`05ae1000   fffff880`05af4000   0x00013000  0x4a5bc18f  14/07/2009 00:21:51                     
vmnetbridge.sys     fffff880`05af4000   fffff880`05b04000   0x00010000  0x4a800d26  10/08/2009 13:05:58                     
lltdio.sys      fffff880`05b04000   fffff880`05b19000   0x00015000  0x4a5bcc92  14/07/2009 01:08:50                     
rspndr.sys      fffff880`05b19000   fffff880`05b31000   0x00018000  0x4a5bcc92  14/07/2009 01:08:50                     
HTTP.sys        fffff880`05b31000   fffff880`05bf9000   0x000c8000  0x4a5bc1a8  14/07/2009 00:22:16                     
bowser.sys      fffff880`05a00000   fffff880`05a1e000   0x0001e000  0x4d6497da  23/02/2011 06:15:06                     
mpsdrv.sys      fffff880`05a1e000   fffff880`05a36000   0x00018000  0x4a5bcc79  14/07/2009 01:08:25                     
mrxsmb.sys      fffff880`05a36000   fffff880`05a63000   0x0002d000  0x4dc0bf1a  04/05/2011 03:51:06                     
mrxsmb10.sys        fffff880`066ce000   fffff880`0671c000   0x0004e000  0x4e17c0a7  09/07/2011 03:44:55                     
mrxsmb20.sys        fffff880`0671c000   fffff880`0673f000   0x00023000  0x4dc0bf19  04/05/2011 03:51:05                     
hcmon.sys       fffff880`0673f000   fffff880`0674b000   0x0000c000  0x4b5a765b  23/01/2010 05:08:59                     
vmci.sys        fffff880`0674b000   fffff880`06763000   0x00018000  0x4b5a6e03  23/01/2010 04:33:23                     
vmx86.sys       fffff880`06896000   fffff880`0696c000   0x000d6000  0x4b5a8e0d  23/01/2010 06:50:05                     
MpNWMon.sys     fffff880`0696c000   fffff880`0697c000   0x00010000  0x4d9cc7fb  06/04/2011 21:07:23                     
peauth.sys      fffff880`06600000   fffff880`066a6000   0x000a6000  0x4a5bd8df  14/07/2009 02:01:19                     
secdrv.SYS      fffff880`0697c000   fffff880`06987000   0x0000b000  0x4508052e  13/09/2006 14:18:38                     
srvnet.sys      fffff880`06987000   fffff880`069b4000   0x0002d000  0x4dba2ca3  29/04/2011 04:12:35                     
tcpipreg.sys        fffff880`069b4000   fffff880`069c6000   0x00012000  0x4a5bcccd  14/07/2009 01:09:49                     
vmnetuserif.sys     fffff880`069c6000   fffff880`069d0000   0x0000a000  0x4b5a7a6b  23/01/2010 05:26:19                     
vstor2-mntapi10.sys     fffff880`069d0000   fffff880`069dc000   0x0000c000  0x49e94462  18/04/2009 04:09:22                     
vstor2-ws60.sys     fffff880`069dc000   fffff880`069e8000   0x0000c000  0x4ad39a52  12/10/2009 22:06:26                     
srv2.sys        fffff880`06800000   fffff880`06867000   0x00067000  0x4dba2cb3  29/04/2011 04:12:51                     
srv.sys     fffff880`06763000   fffff880`067f8000   0x00095000  0x4dba2cc1  29/04/2011 04:13:05                     
NisDrvWFP.sys       fffff880`06867000   fffff880`0687f000   0x00018000  0x4d9cc855  06/04/2011 21:08:53                     
WinRing0x64.sys     fffff880`0687f000   fffff880`06886000   0x00007000  0x488b26c1  26/07/2008 14:29:37                     
asyncmac.sys        fffff880`0aa8f000   fffff880`0aa9a000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bcce5  14/07/2009 01:10:13                     
nvoclk64.sys        fffff880`0aa9a000   fffff880`0aaaa000   0x00010000  0x4ab00e3d  15/09/2009 22:59:25
```

I'd apreciate any help because I'm well outside of my comfort zone.

Comment: You can help by adding computer specific info to your post; i.e. what processor, RAM, Video card, etc. Also, is it one specific game or various ones?

Comment: Certainly. I can't fit everything in the character limit so I'll post in an hour when the 8 hour time limit expires.

Comment: Sounds like a heat problem/faulty component, Could be the Video card or the RAM faulty. Try reseating both - take them out if possible and put back in

Comment: All I was asking for is a simple description like; Brand/model, # GHz processor, GB RAM, video card model, etc. In my experience, a lot of gaming issues are related to hardware compatibility. You can post that info as a comment below this.

Comment: Put everything in your question. If you exceed the character limit, use Pastebin or similar, please.